# Standard notation for repeated function

Tags: calculus, radicals

How does standard mathematical notation apply in the infinitely repeating part in the following example (I have used overbar for infinite repetition)?

$$½√(2-√(2+√(2\;\;\overline{+\text{√}(2+\text{√}(2\text{–}\text{√}(2}$$

Comment: A few dots is probably the way to go, say something along the lines of $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\dots}}}$. Alternatively, you could inductively define a sequence $x_n=\sqrt{2\pm \sqrt{x_n}}$, the $\pm$ depending on whether $n$ is even or odd, and then $x=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ would be the desired quantity, provided the sequence actually converges.

Comment: In the above case, there are two parts- fixed part and repeating part. First three radicals are fixed and later three radicals are repeating infinitely. @Reveillark- does your valuable suggestion work well?